# Iterate over all non-equivalent strings

Tags: code-golf

## Input

A single positive integer \$ 10 \geq n \geq 2\$

## Output

A list of strings, each of length \$2n\$, satisfying the following properties.

- Each string will contain each of the first \$n\$ lowercase letters of the alphabet exactly twice.
- No letter can occur twice consecutively. That is `abbcac` is not allowed.
- No two strings that are `equivalent` can be in the list. Equivalence will be defined below.
- All non-equivalent strings satisfying the rules must be in the list.

## Equivalence

We say that two strings of the same length are equivalent if there is a [bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20bijection%2C%20also,with%20exactly%20one%20element%20of) from the letters in the first string to the letters in the second string which makes them equal. For example, `abcbca` and `bcacab` are equivalent.

## Examples

- \$n = 2\$: `abab`
- \$n = 3\$: `abacbc abcabc abcacb abcbac abcbca`

The length of these lists is [A278990](https://oeis.org/A278990).

Comment: n=2: ab => n=2: abab

Comment: Isn't abacbc equivalent to acabcb?

Comment: @CommandMaster Oops. That was a copy and paste error. Thx

Comment: Is lowercase mandatory, or may the result also be uppercase (e.g. `ABAB`)?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Given the number of answers already, I would like to keep lowercase.

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 45 bytes

```
≔⪪…βＮ¹θ⊞υωＦ⁺θθ≔ΣＥυ⁺κΦθ∧⁻μΦ⮌κ¬π∧‹№κμ²⬤…βν№κξυυ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY_PagIxEMbvfYrgaQLxoHgQepKFQkFF9Cg97K6xG8wmMZPxz7N4sdDSvlIfwnfopFWhAwOT3_fxzeT0VTdlrH1pz-cPSuvu8PsyQjSvDhbBmgTFsba6aHyASolnFyhNqa10BCmV6HFv5ePDjLABUmLP89pHATNLCNssSnGLoxYmZci2X3WjxJOxiZPYN3IrmBjHuL3jud7piBo2vGTqEwSZV2bnWCNC4cmlnNIy7WfF2v_XOoZ310FeSwnKF0fDnKd3rGq8fv1z2enubOflbfD3_gE) Link is to verbose version of code. Theoretically supports `n` up to `26`. Explanation:

```
≔⪪…βＮ¹θ
```

Get the first `n` letters of the lowercase alphabet.

```
⊞υω
```

Start with an empty string.

```
Ｆ⁺θθ
```

Loop `2n` times.

```
≔ΣＥυ⁺κΦθ∧⁻μΦ⮌κ¬π∧‹№κμ²⬤…βν№κξυ
```

For each string so far, create strings with all of the first `n` lowercase letters appended to it, but exclude those that fail to satisfy the criteria.

```
υ
```

Output the final strings.

There are three criteria that are checked when considering candidate letters to append:

- The letter must not already be the last letter of the string
- The letter must not have already appeared twice
- All previous letters must already appear in the string

Comment: Very nice simplification of the rules.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 107 bytes

Returns a single space-separated string.

```javascript
f=(n,s=' ',m=1,i=m,g=q=>i?f(n,"abcdefghij"[--i]+s,+q+m)+g``:q)=>s[2*n]?/(.)(|.*\1.*)\1/.test(s)?'':s:g(m<n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1BboMwEEX3PYUVRcKDjRGRsiFxOESXcSQoMcYRHhdsdUM5O3W6etJ//8@8up8u9Iv9jgX6p973QVLkQWYk405W3ErHjZzlzTZDEofuq3/qwYz2dbgXhX2wwNnMHDDTtvUM8hbupxwfTUkF0F@Rq0rkoKpSRB0iDdBkWR1qQ90VYR/8QicdCRJJTpeEqyTnRMaArB@EvN2iQ7LpN1xS0nsMftJi8oa279lxxU3hcU21jf5DuC72Iy3VJysNiEmjieMGCtt0Ydv/AA)

Or **[106 bytes](https://tio.run/##HY1BboMwEEX3PYUXkZjBxohIVVUSB6lX6DKOBKK2Q4WHgt1uKGenTldP@u//mc/upwv9MnzFgqYPs@9WAYmgMpYJryoxKC@cmtVlKIrGJvX2ba1Z4Drw15cb8iD4zD1y17b1jOoSrsecbk0JEuFX5rqSOeqqlNGECAGbLKtD7cCfCXc7LTCayIgpdjwlnBV7TuQc2frE2MMtJiSbHuMpJf1EYRqNHCcH7WN2WGnTdFhTbYN/SN/F/g6lfuelQzkacvG@oaY2Xdj2Pw)** in Node.js.

#### Method

We recursively build all non-equivalent strings of length \$2n\$ with \$n\$ distinct characters. The non-equivalence is enforced by using an upper bound \$m\$ which is initialized to \$1\$ and incremented as soon as the \$m\$-th character has been inserted and while we have \$m<n\$.

The other criteria are tested at the end of the recursion with a regular expression which should *not* be matched by a valid string:

```javascript
/(.)(|.*\1.*)\1/
```

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (                // f is a recursive function taking:
  n,                 //   n = input
  s = ' ',           //   s = current output string
  m = 1,             //   m = upper character bound
  i = m,             //   i = counter
  g = q =>           //   g is a recursive function taking a flag q:
    i ?              //     if i is not zero:
      f(             //       1st recursive call to f:
        n,           //         pass n unchanged
        "abcdefghij" //         lookup string of letters
        [--i]        //         decrement i and append the i-th letter
        + s,         //         followed by s
        +q + m       //         increment m if q is set
      )              //       end of recursive call
      + g``          //       2nd recursive call to g with q zero'ish
    :                //     else:
      q              //       stop (at this point, we have q = [''])
) =>                 //
  s[2 * n] ?         // if s has 2n + 1 characters:
    /(.)(|.*\1.*)\1/ //   if there's any character in s immediately
    .test(s) ?       //   followed by itself or appearing 3+ times:
      ''             //     s is invalid, so append nothing
    :                //   else:
      s              //     append s
  :                  // else:
    g(m < n)         //   initial call to g with q set if m < n
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 69 bytes

```
.+
*
Y`\_`l
^
<$'>
/>./+Lrv$`(?(2)(\3.+))<(.+)?(\w)
$%`$1$3<$2$%'
<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0@bS4srMiEmPiGHK47LRkXdjkvfTk9f26eoTCVBw17DSFMjxlhPW1PTRgNI2mvElGtyqagmqBiqGNuoGKmoqnPZ2HH9/28CAA) Might work up to `n=26`. Explanation:

```
.+
*
Y`\_`l
```

Generate the first `n` lowercase letters.

```
^
<$'>
```

Make a duplicate set, and wrap the first set in `<` and `>`.

```
Lrv$`(?(2)(\3.+))<(.+)?(\w)
$%`$1$3<$2$%'
```

For each string, make new strings by either a) moving the first character from the first set or b) moving a character from the second set that was moved from the first set but not in the immediately previous iteration.

```
/>./+`
```

Repeat until the second set is empty for all strings.

```
<>
```

Remove the `<>` markers.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>18</s>  15 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly)

```
Øaḣx2Œ!Q⁼Ɲ;QƊÐṂ
```

A monadic Link that accepts \$n\$ and yields a list of lists of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wjMSHOxZXGB2dpBj4qHHPsbnWgce6Dk94uLPp/@H2yP@JSYnJSclciUnJiVAqOQlEAYXBVHLif2MA)**

#### How?

```
Øaḣx2Œ!Q⁼Ɲ;QƊÐṂ - Link: n
Øa              - alphabet
  ḣ             - head to index {n}
   x2           - times two
     Œ!         - all permutations
       Q        - deduplicate
             ÐṂ - keep those {P in those permutations} minimal under:
         Ɲ      -   to neighbouring pairs {P}:
        ⁼       -     equal?
           Q    -   deduplicate {P}
          ;     -   concatenate ...e.g. 'accbab' -> [0,1,0,0,0,'a','c','b']
                          (minimal entries would be [0,0,0,..,0,'a','b','c',...])
```

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 127 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,z=[],L)=>[...n?f(n-1,[c=(n+9).toString(36),...z],c+[L]):z+z?[]:[L],...z.flatMap(t=>t==L[0]?[]:f(n,z.filter(y=>y!=t),t+L))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY2xCsIwFEV3/8Itj6ZBrQhWXvsDcXIMGUJsSiUkpX0Izc/H1lG3yzkH7su8zWynYaQyxGeXs0MWeEKluQRslBAitI6F8siVXVVxBUHxQdMQelZdgK9B0twWSmqoU5Fapet1f7lw3tDdjIywIUSpDnrTbnsQbvDUTWzBZtkjAadCAuh829kY5ug74WPPHDsB/JDqj5wB8gc)

[Its `print` version](https://tio.run/##Zcy9CsIwFEDh3bdwyyXXoFbEH1JfIJtjyFBCUyo1Ke2l0JB3j3HV9XxwXs3SzHbqR9otl5ydZB6j1AYVyDqKdzMykjVJqfTepOS@LFw/UDuxVdbrVhIgcQXoHwV3B9S2PPgVBIUnTb3vWHUGFEJEg5ZrZeAWeUxpLEZMAeT7xrEjoA1@DkMrhtAxKKn6T6eflD8) is 116 bytes

Comment: Could you add an explanation?  Base 36 is already confusing ;)

Comment: @Simd To convert number into letter

Answer (score 3):

## Python3, 323 bytes:

```py
def B(a,b):
 d={}
 for a,b in zip(a,b):
  if b not in(T:=d.get(a,[])):d[a]={*T,b}
 return d
def F(n):
 r,q=[],[['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'[:n]*2,'']]
 for s,k in q:
  if''==s:
   if all(any(len(K)>1for K in B(j,k).values())for j in r):r+=[k]
  for i,a in enumerate(s):q+=[[s[:i]+s[i+1:],k+a]]*(k==''or a!=k[-1])
 return r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVCxbsIwFNzzFe5kP@IiAR2QJXdgYGFlszw4jQHHwUlshxZQvz21i6i6ne7u3bv3@ms8dW617v001fqANkTRCliBan7/LtCh8ygRyDh0M/1TQ@aAKuS6mHiyZ7yeH3VMopAArBZK8vtsT6s073UcvUN1kbO3xOVpTwcuJBUCq@oj8ceTaWx7dl0/@BDHy@fX9YYFc3K2pBhL@WgRqM0thsd6jDkPGeYqqm2JclfSakd28L7I9l02b0hDLcwvqh11IABZaLLggfmSC5uyf8MNVZnWbjxrr6ImAdiQDCIIZmQZhCkXTFJbKilnxHKOcX7MC7fidSHh704/9d64SLZkCVA88eoffgOYfgA)

Comment: You can save 8 bytes by replacing `ascii_lowercase` and its import with the literal `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`

Comment: @yoniLavi Thank you, updated

Answer (score 3):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 18 bytes

```
r:,↕ũ∆Zç∫:ux=¿97+H
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FruLrHQetU09uvJRR1vU4eWPOlZblVbYHtpvaa7tsaQ4KbkYqm7BYiMuYwgTAA)

```
r:,↕ũ∆Zç∫:ux=¿97+H
r:,↕ũ               Find a list of length 2n that contains each number from 0 to n exactly twice
r                       Range from 0 to input
 :                      Duplicate
  ,                     Join
   ↕ũ                   Permutation
     ∆Zç∫           Check that no two adjacent values are equal
     ∆                  Delta
      Z                 Check no values are 0
       ç                Prepend 0
        ∫               Cumsum to get back to the original list
         :ux=¿      Check that the list is in the standard order
         :              Duplicate
          u             Uniquify
           x=           Check that the result is [0, 1, 2, ..., n]
             ¿          If so, get back to the original list
              97+H  Convert to string
              97+       Add 97
                 H      Convert from codepoints to string
```

Comment: You might win the prize for the slowest code.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3.10/), 204 bytes

```python
from itertools import*
def f(n):z,F='abcdefghij'[:n],frozenset;q=F();return[x for x in permutations(z*2)if all(a!=b for a,b in pairwise(x))and q!=(q:=q|{F(F(I for I,c in enumerate(x)if c==d)for d in z)})]
```

Testable as `f(n)`, outputs list of tuples. Each tuple contains "characters" (strings of length 1) and is thus equivalent to a string.

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 205 bytes

`itertools.pairwise` was added in 3.10 and is not supported by TIO, so here's another version:

```python
from itertools import*
def f(n):z,F='abcdefghij'[:n],frozenset;q=F();return[x for x in permutations(z*2)if all(a!=b for a,b in zip(x,x[1:]))and q!=(q:=q|{F(F(I for I,c in enumerate(x)if c==d)for d in z)})]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzBboMwEETv@QrnlN3IlyY9VES@IuUbEAcDduMK1mZZJJe2304DUqXeRjNvXvqUR6TrW@J19RwHFcSxxNhPKgwpspwPnfPKA2Gx6NKcbNM@i/dH@DhVBdX6eVocTU5uoykBb@xkZqqy8pFVVoFUcjzMYiVEmmA5XzB4Zfse7NE0O2V1s3FLSJB1rl6KGtFSp8ajgbEw4/dXCSXcd/au2411NA@OrTjIm641psNt7nYR/mC9Jg4k4OGCePjL13/5FXH9BQ)

Works by simple bruteforce, will likely time out for \$n \ge 6\$.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 17 (or 16<sup>*†*</sup>) [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
L€DœÙʒDüÊ*ÙāQ}.bl
```

Output as a list of lists.

*†*: Could be -1 byte removing the trailing `l` by outputting in uppercase.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9vc2FiaWX//0zigqxExZPDmcqSRMO8w4oqw5nEgVF9LmJs//8z) or [verify both test cases](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9vc2FiaWX/MkVOPkQ/IiDihpIgIj//TOKCrETFk8OZypJEw7zDiirDmcSBUX0uYmz/LP8).

**Explanation:**

```python
L        # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input-integer]
 €D      # Duplicate each value within the list
   œ     # Get all permutations of this list
    Ù    # Uniquify it
ʒ        # Filter this list of lists by:
 D       #  Duplicate the current list
  ü      #  For each overlapping pair:
   Ê     #   Check that they are NOT equal
    *    #  Multiply the values in the lists at the same positions
         #  (removing the trailing item, but this doesn't matter)
     Ù   #  Uniquify it
      ā  #  Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping)
       Q #  Check whether the two lists are the same
}.b      # After the second filter: convert all integers to their 1-based alphabetic
         # uppercase letters
   l     # Convert those to lowercase
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: You are not outputting strings.

Comment: Strings are sequences of characters, so it's the same thing. Both are allowed by default: [see this meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2214/whats-a-string/) and [this 'default input/output methods' meta answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25275/52210).

Comment: Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 161 bytes

```perl
sub{$_=substr(abcdefghij,0,pop)x2;my%r;1while s/^(.*)(.)(.*)(.)(??{($t="$1$4$3$2$'")=~m,(.)(\1|.*(.).*\3(??{$1lt$3})),||$r{$t}++;$s{$t}++||''})/$1$4$3$2/;keys%r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZddU1tHDIbv@RU77qHYjgcCJP3A48B9Z5qb3oU2s9KKhJav2O4kDNC/Tlfafd/DTMvNeZB19GpX0q59Z@urt8/Dxep587c8DB9X9bHZrqdZtNjFp8@Xfy5eL@5u72bfjpbX97vr5eHXz5dXljYHf0z357Pp/gyP09OH6bBdTYbD4c1wPBwNe5PZ6p/rhX92fvi4P6@wPz8/dsfh8Go7HD/NZovHx2H9MGyfXr1aDpsGj497e0@zA8Q5WP5l95vd9dPzcufidj3dSelDOkqrd@nL12nKkiXN0u@LMB@/MKtofWjuDxV/VHM8NI8vvXkZS4uW9jagCKFog/phhyJNozlrOAX0txyKVpnxL4wKtx5Bco9QX8sNSlZAaUkXxUfVyaHkrlLy/6iU3FU8kjQobTc8ZLNIVynSVYp0FV9BU/FUOmj@j4qvvkNX8dV06BE8wQ7yYuff9p3vG2/Feg1MX6AVYHUhmvYil/6ab8uIiBBoKCkiBPYIdZ14rYRzR0ZwNLQAIzga@4ER6ksCNCkjIkINNTpU54YmVDOhmgnVPJYCTelg6ElTqplSzZRqvh6oeWrEAqvvBJFqvjoiI3iaRO1TgFrEQIzYd7KhFWBbW0PDkDJC2@COfSe1LxnY1qY9H8wdXmM1HZkDqxlYRgfkwGrGdJoAmQOrGVhGB@aAajaEL6rZEGqoZsMCq1IN1QykGqoZaEIHK7D2ajakWq9mQ0bo1WzIkxK1kMxqSmY1JbOakllNyaxmD4dTbUTLL9Bw7Fl1IVrGGYjXSkY1KzIHR8MxyRxCjGcmI4RcR@bgiAjKHGLBPQfLVLNMNctU81gKNKWD4dw2pZop1Uyp5uuBmqdGLLD6ThCp5qsjMoKnSVTeFH0fSuZcVMROBhouE@xkoCluE0bgXHhaUkZEBM5FqyBvHwrHEHU00RGhFn1PRAROViDUOFmBiMDJCiywKvPlZEVDCa3Ml5PV2gzWwnw5WdF8jFDGfDFZrSV552InhV1dkbUQdrVjGR2wNmFXF2FXe1q5jIgI7Op2NvJOp3CMQEfLOiLUomuJiMC5CIQa5yIQETgXgfimwbkIZARlvpyL6JxMB8M3E85FINUK8@VcxAmf6YC50MyubidwR3a1Zna1ZnZ17D@/7TCCsBYqrIUKa6HCWsQ08dsRhWN/OlqWEaFWZUcHQQTLzNffKkDm69kIEF0dTQKrMF9XgIMwX98RqAlqESMPa2G@vkrELczXd4@@lulQ9QItc7otc7otc7pjlQpER8WCYeV0W@Z0W@Z0R88KEPsQ7Qsrpzt2D3E53dHf9MV0R6vDasLMTJiZKdVMqWaFEQzfyU04WSacLBNOVtRKgdwH4WSZcLJMOFkmnKw4RzMQ1YwjFVZOVvQA4nKy4sylLyYrjl9YLTMzy8zMlGqmVLPCCD69DZVdbcquNmVXx/khQFZT2dWm7GpTdrUpuzpuA6ixq@NigJVdHecS4rKr4@agL7o6LhFYLTMzy8zMhGomVLPCCD45DeP2JqIWcSMTkVlcjER0VNw5REYQVjNuDCCrGedyR@U@xJkI5D7EOQfkPsRp0tEyM7PMzEyo5r0KVEbwysVPxu/Shx9W7xr8CPgJ8DPg8HXQ7CF@ol7fT4ebxZl9u5ulVTobPi53mjmdfbrdVtPmdr1N3w8X1W3WPrtbX95sLya7m5RuqsNwc37j5hrCdGvlJHm0ZqshTtpPYY92fjNZpIl/Okn2pVK1TdJp2nv/y146SXvz@fzX97@l@t9y52nn@V8)

```perl
$f=
sub{
  $_=substr(abcdefghij,0,pop)x2;         #set $_ to first n chars times 2
  my%r;                                  #init %r where results are collected
  1 while                                #repeat while untested perms exists
    s/                                   #permute $_ by swap of two random chars
    ^(.*)(.)(.*)(.)
       (??{
        $t="$1$4$3$2$'";                 #test new permutation in $t
        $t=~
        m,(.)(\1|.*(.).*\3(??{$1lt$3})), #two of same not neighbors and
                                         #no higher char before two equal lower
        ||                               #if no error then tests passed and...
        $r{$t}++;                        #register current perm $t as a result
        $s{$t}++||''                     #register current perm as seen/done
       })
    /$1$4$3$2/x;                         #if not seen change $_ to new perm
  keys%r                                 #return registered results
}
;
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <del>528</del> 521 bytes

Port of [@Ajax1234's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264123/110802) in Scala.

**521 bytes, it can be golfed much more.**

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZFBb9swDIXv/RVaTiTicsu2kzMHGIYeBqwYhmCnIChkm05Uy7ItyWkT1789k91kKDadyAfx8dOTy6SW5zp95MyLe6mM6G@EyLkQVWhA2p2LxVdr5XGz9laZ3RZj8dsoL5LpphBNUL02UMBHxH@UT/8pnydlOI8bUpDxq2mUXgpM4F42xFXjj5tve2mjNfup2G7fx5JOqoEUsYc8ajBZ5XNo6GFxu4Kcdux/2jvteJLGuVcbnIsgBLbhZlxagIm/G49Jf5BatIkbA6Cs1jokoGpDVedlqpl@ddzxBi6AF7wtwBQGFUrr8GCYyTQLtru9eix1Zeqmtc53h6fn42lGrkvdNAcfIoNIVXlxm80QlwdphU1@KOev0QIun/ZKM7RkanM30Y@Y4K45lX9zainndkRcqgIcKXe5HjpLRW1l4FsnqxTWUYkUTDp2xM9hm4MHcurEqwWGJG1SxrEdBg7J9WEO1JfbYGdylbGb7Mqr@cuLA4XvkpK0dB77lthMCBAA3r5V4fytoOYLjMr5OBx@IZylJcsHto6Xw3k4/wE)

```scala
def b(a:String,b:String)=(Map.empty[Char,Set[Char]]/:a.zip(b)){(d,p)=>d+(p._1->(d.getOrElse(p._1,Set.empty)+ p._2))}
def f(n:Int)={val q=scala.collection.mutable.Queue[(String,String)]((Array.fill(2)("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".substring(0,n)).mkString,""));var r=List[String]();while(q.nonEmpty){val(s:String,k:String)=q.dequeue;if(s.isEmpty){if(r.forall(S=>b(S,k).values.exists(_.size>1))){r=k::r}}else{for(i<-s.indices){if(k.isEmpty||s(i)!=k.last){q.enqueue((s.substring(0,i)+s.substring(i+1),k+s(i)))}}}};r.reverse;}
```

Ungolfded version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVLLbtswELz7K7Y@kYhD1G1PQmOgaHMokKAojJ4MI6Cklc2IohSScmI7/nZnRUm23AA5idrH7MzsukRqeTyW8SMmHu6lMrAfAaSYQUE/TNqVi@CHtXK7mHurzGrJI/hnlIebUAlQUdRrwzJl0jk@1WgSdOwL5x9kv36Y/Rayh1FHJK6VTn@pxKvSSLtlMoKWygTi/kmk7mW1@LmWdgJz9OG1XJ5ISrFTFYu5yEqd3mHmGZULLCq/fdfEYQ8spXkTqKSyHG5mAYPYUBCugDVh8TCF61lbKFbo/9hb7bBPBbwWn1NHG@09OQzVXUo3Efw2ntTcKed7x08qNtKCIu@V1G2KMmE3IlNak@dsLOOEUFdr9ZjrwpTVk3W@3jy/bHdj4erYhTb2eWI4F0XeonTYGohFjYTpmqsQSak1BtdFUXsZaxR/m4IF6@3vvF8ydsFqAuNxJ7VhbNHVurmXoSbGR6Hgea00sjBYmNLcto7tO8MbUsyd952f9k1wbVOK4dvjAaiMOaHcf0gh3jKhG7CS7CI7aLXvzovCNIgLml2jE/hCrB17EE7tEGYw5XyICmd5OURR93dKH7rXAZCuY9BHHJiC79dAXA3dELpLVGKb9yrg9RUcUxw@0RChpfOXtdBZgaa1gvQPVw2qOcFhTF1NOWlsogTbreqS8IB6d7Ojs1hhcYPWYbjjw@h4fAM)

```scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(findSequences(2))
    println(findSequences(3))
    println(findSequences(4))
  }

  def buildDictionary(a: String, b: String): Map[Char, Set[Char]] = {
    a.zip(b).foldLeft(Map.empty[Char, Set[Char]]) { (dict, pair) =>
      dict + (pair._1 -> (dict.getOrElse(pair._1, Set.empty) + pair._2))
    }
  }

  def findSequences(n: Int): List[String] = {
    var initialString = Array.fill(2)("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".substring(0,n)).mkString
    val queue = scala.collection.mutable.Queue[(String, String)]((initialString, ""))
    var result = List[String]()

    while(queue.nonEmpty) {
      val (s: String, k: String) = queue.dequeue()

      if(s.isEmpty) {
        if(result.forall(sub => buildDictionary(sub, k).values.exists(_.size > 1))) {
          result = k :: result
        }
      } else {
        for(i <- s.indices) {
          if(k.isEmpty || s(i) != k.last) {
            queue.enqueue((s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i+1), k + s(i)))
          }
        }
      }
    }

    result.reverse
  }
}
```